# Dispose a texture in as3 Starling

Tags: apache-flex, air, starling-framework, actionscript-3

I am currently working on an application where a screenshot of the stage is generated as bitmap image and the generated image is then added to a tab in the application.

I am unable to add more than a few screenshot images to the tab. The application throws "Error #3691: Resource limit for this resource type exceeded" exception.

I found that this exception is thrown because of the texture not being disposed properly.
In the code below, If I dispose the bufferedTexture, the image added to the tab is empty.

Below is the code:

```
public function AddtoMediaTab():void
{
   var buffer:BitmapData;
   buffer = GetStageAsBitmapData();
   var bufferedTexture:Texture = Texture.fromBitmapData(buffer);
   this.image.source = bufferedTexture;
   buffer.dispose();
   buffer = null;
  //bufferedTexture.dispose(); 
  //bufferedTexture = null;
}

public function GetAsBitmapData():BitmapData
{
    var buffer:BitmapData = new BitmapData(this.width,this.height, false, 0x000000);
    this.media.DrawToBitmap(buffer);
    return buffer;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: so you know how to dispose a texture with starling ... and your question is?

Comment: The size of the image is probably too large, how big is your stage? Obviously disposing of it will delete it, so of course the image wont appear.

Comment: @BennettYeates: The size my stage is 1920x1080. Is there any way I could reduce the size of the image and then save it?

Comment: @BotMaster: Sorry If I was not clear with my question. When I dispose the texture, the image is empty. so is there any way to reduce the size of the image before adding it to the tab? Currently the size of the image is 1920x1080 and I am using an ImageLoader to display the image in the tab.

Comment: Anything that is displayed via Stage3D (like starling) has to be uploaded to the graphic card in order to be available for display. For that reason it cannot be disposed at all if you need to display it. You can only dispose it once you don't need it anymore. Of course uploading to GPU has limits and once you reach them you'll either get a resource limit error or crash on mobile devices. It is you the coder that is in charge of managing that part and make sure at any point in time only what you really need is uploaded and what you don't is disposed.

Comment: That line: Texture.fromBitmapData(buffer); does upload to GPU btw.

Comment: @BotMaster is correct. Also that image size is well within limits, so perhaps you are creating too many images and that is why you are getting that error.

Comment: @BotMaster: Thank you very much for your reply. I have set Starling.handleLostContext = false to stop starling from caching the textures in RAM.

Comment: That shouldn't make much difference.

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing the rendering profile. Straight from the Starling API documentation:

[starling.core.Starling API](http://doc.starling-framework.org/core/)

> **Context3D Profiles**
>
> Stage3D supports different rendering profiles, and
>   Starling works with all of them. The last parameter of the Starling
>   constructor allows you to choose which profile you want. The following
>   profiles are available:
>
> - BASELINE_CONSTRAINED: provides the broadest hardware reach. If you
>     develop for the browser, this is the profile you should test with.
> - BASELINE: recommend for any mobile application, as it allows Starling
>     to use a more memory efficient texture type (RectangleTextures). It
>     also supports more complex AGAL code.
> - BASELINE_EXTENDED: adds support
>     for textures up to 4096x4096 pixels. This is especially useful on
>     mobile devices with very high resolutions.
>
> The recommendation is to
>   deploy your app with the profile "auto" (which makes Starling pick the
>   best available of those three), but test it in all available profiles.